# why can indentation not start in the second loop with an extra indent

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor

```py
y=int(input('Enter a value:'))
if y>10:
    print('number is greater than 10')
       if y<100:
            print('it is less than 100')
       print('end of inner block')
    print('end of outer block')
print('out of all blocks')
```

getting an error in line 4 , where indentation is intentionally added to see how the code behaves. why is python showing an error.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the extra indentation:

```
y=int(input('Enter a value:'))
if y>10:
    print('number is greater than 10')
    if y<100:
        print('it is less than 100')**strong text**
        print('end of inner block')
    print('end of outer block')
print('out of all blocks')
```

Output:

```
number is greater than 10
it is less than 100
end of inner block
end of outer block
out of all blocks
```

Comment: why do i need to remove that indentation, will python not recognize it as a loop within a loop ?

Comment: @Gopi Nope in python you need to be exact

Answer (score 1):

indentation error is very common when you're coding in Python. Make sure you use "TAB" key whenever you start new loop or new block. In python, scope of function is replaced by "tab/space" but kindly try to avoid giving space as you'll always need to give redundant spaces. It's better just use Tab key instead. And for your code correction. The answer given by above is correct.

Welcome to python world !!

Happy Coding.
Cheers !!!